# Database for student and progress attendance web application

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

In the project I want to do I will be requiring a database for the following:

- Store and access login details for Admin, Managers and Faculty.
- Store students and their information, i.e. Phone numbers, emails, level within the language, what class they will be in, exam results, and an attendance tracker, comments on student.
- Class group and its information, level in language, students in group(relational database to link with students through class code), current progress, exam results, and a register which will interact with attendance tracker. comment on groups, and exercises
- Academies and groups in the academies. 5 Companies and their groups. level in language, students in group(relational database to link with students through class code), current progress, exam results, and a register which will interact with attendance tracker. comment on groups, and exercises

I will be requiring the different users of the site namely the staff to be able to work with all this information and adjust accordingly. Potentially having 60-120 staff using it at one time to communicate different details about their classes as they finish with each class.

Now I am trying to find out what database would be best for this.

I have worked with SQLite a bit, and been learning a bit about PostgreSQL, but if it is better to use the likes of Mysql I may go for it, but judging by whats needed which form would be best. and if using the likes of Mysql or PostgreSQL where would it be best to host the database for access? Or would SQLite be good enough with this considering staff-wise we would be looking at a maximum of 160 at one time online with the web app and database wise the will all be related through group codes and the students?

Bare in mind have not worked with MySQL or PostgreSQL yet also, just trying to under which would be best.

The main question is which would be better to be used for what – and which would best suit my purpose.

Comment: To be honest: It doesn't really matter. Take whichever you want. There are differences in their capabilities and the syntax, but those differences are really minimal.

Comment: even sqlite would work?

Comment: Of course! The data you are generating is really minimal. SQLite can cope with much larger databases!

Comment: even with multiple people accessing it at once

Comment: It depends. If they all want to write, I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: well if they need to submit multiple different classes at once... It will be used by many users submitting different classroom at the same time between classes... Hence why i asked the question as to which one to use

Comment: Do you manage to get a web app for this? I was looking for the same thing.

Comment: Hey I developed the app with sqlite and then once I had it functional I migrated to postgre and then deployed it with postgre